# <link rel="icon" href=""> Causing my Wordpress functions to execute twice

Tags: buddypress, wp-load.php

As my title says, today I spent more than 5 hours figuring out why when I tried to add a new activity to buddypress (via bp_activity_add) It would be added twice or even three times.

I started deleting includes, and then line by line until I deleted

```
<link rel="icon" href="">
```

and all of a sudden bp_activity_add started to work as intended (adding one activity per refresh)

My question to you guys is WHY? Why does this line causes to bp_activity_add to duplicate entries?

To be clear this is the code that duplicates what was happening to me:

```
<?php 
session_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <link rel="icon" href="">
    </head>

<?php 
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp/wp-load.php';
function OurNewactivity($user_id,$link_to_route_activity,$activityHTML){
    $activity_id = bp_activity_add( array(
        'action'            => $activityHTML,
        'content'           => 'some info here:d',
        /* the component argument will be set to our component's identifier */
        'component'         => 'bp_plugin',
        /* the type argument will be set to our component's type */
        'type'              => 'New activity',
                'user_id'  => $user_id,
    'primary_link'=> $link_to_route_activity,
    ) );
 return $activity_id;
}
    $results=OurNewactivity($user_id,$link_to_route_activity,$activityHTML);
    var_dump($results);
    ?>
```

Comment: Depending on where this code lives, it could be the 404 page called in the background when your browser tries to load an inexistant icon file... Look at your browser console for 404 errors, then look at the returned response...

Comment: it doesnt show any 404.. i guess because there is no route specified

Comment: So where is this code, exactly?

Comment: That's the whole page..

Comment: Right - but which page is it? Homepage? Specialized template?

Comment: a .php file sitting outside wordpress

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55092/discussion-between-raulnd-and-macprawn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right - so the explanation, it turns out, and with hindsight, is quite simple...

Because the href attribute is empty, it is interpreted as a relative URL, the same URL as the current page.

So every time the page loads, the favicon tries to reload the exact same page - resulting in the double code run observed.

Computers are dumb and always do *exactly* as they are told...